# Get a specific id/class (typescript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, for-loop

**Get the ion-label textContent and add it to an ion-input value.**
*Clicking a specific id or class adds the textContent to an input value*

```
    <ion-item>
        <ion-input type="text" id="item" ></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of toDoList, index as i, let x = index">
        <ion-label id="{{i+0}}" class="element-" [ngClass]="'element-'+x" (click)="doit()">{{item.getX}}</ion-label>
        <ion-button expand="full" (click)="remove(item.getX)">
            <ion-icon name="trash-outline" color="danger"></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>
    </ion-item> 

 

doit() {
    let id = (<HTMLLabelElement>document.getElementById('0')).textContent;
    (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('item')).value = id;
  }
```

Comment: You should describe the problem you have, if you are expecting help.

Comment: **I have already solved the problem. Thank you so much!**  `HTML [(ngModel)]="data”(ion-input) - TS this.data = this.toDoList[index]. getX;`.